# Find indices for colums that match criteria

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix

```
B =   
     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1
     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0
```

I want to return the indices of the columns where the first value is "0" and the fourth value is "1". In this case this would be `(1, 3)`.

How do I obtain the intended output in MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
find(B(1,:) == 0 & B(4,:) == 1)
```

This results in

```
ans =

     1     3
```

Comment: I knew I was overthinking the problem when I considered things with loop, elegantly simple -- +1! Thank you.